# A cyclinder is homotopic to a mobius strip

Tags: algebraic-topology

Here's the problem:
Let $X=[0,1] \times S^1$. Let $\mu$ be a mobius strip. Show that $X$ and $\mu$ are homotopic.

For the proof, I believe it has two parts.
First, I will have to show that $X$ is homotopic to $S^1$.
Second, I'll show that $\mu$ is also homotopic to $S^1$.

But, I do not know how start like what functions to consider and how to represent everything. Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: Deformation retract both onto a loop.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to MSE!

You have the exact right idea! We'll show both $X$ and $\mu$ are homotopic to $S^1$. This will show they're homotopic to each other. The idea will be to take the $S^1$ living "in the middle" of both spaces as a deformation retract.

To show $X \sim S^1$, there is an obvious deformation retract: Look at $\{1/2\} \times S^1 \subseteq X$ and try the linear homotopy
$(r, \theta) \mapsto (r(1-t) + \frac{1}{2} t, \theta)$.

To show $\mu \sim S^1$, there is a slightly trickier one. If we think of $\mu = [0,1] \times [0,1] \big / (r,0) \sim (1-r,1)$, then we will again retract onto $\{1/2\} \times S^1$. It turns out the same homotopy $(r, \theta) \mapsto (r(1-t) + \frac{1}{2} t, \theta)$ will work, but now it's a bit tricker to see why. I'll give an explanation under the fold, but you should take some time (and draw some pictures!) to make sure you really understand what's going on.

> It retracts $[0,1] \times [0,1]$ to $\{1/2\} \times [0,1]$, but then applying our quotient that $(r,0) \sim (1-r,1)$, we find $(1/2, 0) \sim (1/2, 1)$. That is, $\mu \sim \{ 1/2 \} \times S^1$, as desired.

---

I hope this helps ^_^